# android sdk public variable accessing in event onClick()

Tags: android, events, onclick

```
public int testb;
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
           public void onClick(View v) {
                   *********
}}
```

How to access testb variable inside the onClick() method ??

Comment: Can you show the complete code? If it is a instance variable it should be accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally

```java
public class Test{
  public int testb;
  public void myFunc(){
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
       System.out.println( Test.this.testb );
     }
   } );
  }
}
```